# Write a SQL query to tell which week of the year had the max number of sales grouped by country for last 6 months?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write a query which will return the week of the year which had the maximum number of sales for each of the countries in the last 6 months.
So far I tried

```
select country_id, datepart(week, order_date) as weekofyear, count(order_id) from order_table group by country_id,weekofyear having count(order_id) = (select count(order_id) as c from order_table group by country_id order by c limit 1);
```

Kindly help.

Comment: How do you define week of year?

Comment: using the datepart function to get the count of the week in a calender year. For example 1st Feb would fall in week 5 of a year.

Comment: A given date isn't necessary in the same week year to year.

Answer (score 0):

create a subquery that sales shows totals by each week then subquery the results and find the max sales for a week. partition using row_number order by country_id, weekofyear, and sales occcurences descending.

```
select *
from
(
select country_id
,weekofyear
,occurrences
,row_number() over(partition by country_id order by country_id,occurrences desc) row_id
from
(

select distinct country_id,datepart(week,order_date) weekofyear, count(order_id) occurrences from orders
where order_date is not null
group by country_id,datepart(week,order_date)
)x
)y
where row_id=1
```

Comment: start by grouping country and weekofyear with count.  get the results and confirm they are correct.  next, partition the results and produce row_id sorting by the largest occurrence per country then output only the top results